# How to modify in OS X El Capitan‎ the list of Mail.app's email aliases via the command line

Tags: mail.app, macos, email, alias

In OS X El Capitan‎ the Mail app (Version 9.2, storage version V3) presents the list of email aliases in the UI not anymore as a string of comma-separated email addresses. This makes it very cumbersome to bulk edit (like removing duplicates etc...) if you have a decent amount of aliases (say 20 or 30).

Is there a way to read and write this list of aliases via the command line? I looked through the `defaults` domain "`com.apple.mail`" but could not find anything. Then I looked through the plist files inside `~/Library/Mail/V3/` (like `MailData/VIPSenders.plist`) but couldn't find anything either.

Where is this list of aliases stored?